# simple replacement of variables on wolfram-mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

I would like to make a simple replacement or substitution:
y=a+b
a=2d+e
b=f+g
How make Wolfram-Mathematica automatically show and make the substitution or replacement of variables **a** and **b** an show this result:
y=2d+e  +  f+g

?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
y==a+b/.{a->2d+e,b->f+g}
```

and see if that is what you are looking for.

That takes the expression y==a+b and does the list of substitutions to it